# Unable to get title of a youtube video

Tags: json, html, video, youtube

I need a valid code for my blog(blogger) to get Title of YouTube video using the following string:

"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/EDV-KMBvMck?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true"

(This string works well in Internet Explorer)

I have gone through various method found here, but no result are displaying.

I would like to display the titles of the videos within td tag.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    table#t01 {
      width: 100%;
    }
    table#t01,
    th,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <table id="t01">
      <col style="width:50%;">
        <col style="width:50%;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDV-KMBvMck" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/EDV-KMBvMck/default.jpg"" alt="YouTube Icon"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <script>
                $Video_Id = 'EDV-KMBvMck'
                $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$Video_Id}?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true", function(json) {
                    console.log("success");
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(json. {
                      $Video_Id
                    }, function(key1, val1) {
                      $Value = val1.key + val1.val
                    });
                    echo $Value
                  })
                  .done(function() {
                    console.log("second success");
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                  })
                  .always(function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                  })
                  .error(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yXL7dT7ovEM" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/yXL7dT7ovEM/default.jpg"" alt="YouTube Icon"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <script>
                $Video_Id = 'yXL7dT7ovEM'
                $.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{$Video_ID}?v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true", function(json) {
                    console.log("success");
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(json. {
                      $Video_Id
                    }, function(key1, val1) {
                      $Value = val1.key + val1.val
                    });
                    echo $Value
                  })
                  .done(function() {
                    console.log("second success");
                  })
                  .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                  })
                  .always(function() {
                    console.log("complete");
                  })
                  .error(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like a function in header which will call from td tag at every change of Video_Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

paste it into your page and make necessary changes. It works in Firefox, MSIE, Chrome, Opera and just about any new browser out there.